# Diagonalize the Swap operator $\mathbb{S}_\text{AB} = \sum_{i,j=1}^{d} |i_\text{A}j_\text{B}\rangle \langle j_\text{A}i_\text{B}| $

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, quantum-information

I am given the bipartite swap operator $\mathbb{S}_\text{AB}  = \sum_{i,j=1}^{d} |i_\text{A}j_\text{B}\rangle \langle j_\text{A}i_\text{B}| $ that swap the states of two qubits relative to a fixed basis {$|i_\text{A}\rangle \otimes |j_\text{B} \rangle$} and am supposed to diagonalize it. The task is explicitly to not do it by calculating the characteristic polynomial, but considering the effect of the operator on basis vectors in order to construct eigenvectors.\

My approach was that for $i \neq j$ in 2 dimensions, $\mathbb{S}_\text{AB}$ works like an X operator on each of the qubits, so that $\mathbb{S}_\text{AB} = X_A \otimes X_B$, such that the eigenvectors can be constructed analogouosly to {$|\pm \rangle$} in 2 dimensions. I am stuck at the point how to generalize this 2dimensional to d dimensions. Since the exercise aims for an intuitive approach, I would be thankful for a hint how to describe the effect of the operator better.

Comment: it sends $|i,j\rangle$ to $|j,i\rangle$, so what's its action on $|i,j\rangle\pm|j,i\rangle$?

Comment: Think about what states don't change much when you swap the qubits.. think of bosons and fermions